# Input element not aligning "flush" to DIV container

Tags: asp.net, html, css, input

I have been laying out a GUI uing ASP.NET and find I am confused by the rendering of the `<asp:TextBox />` control. It seems as though some default margin is added to the left and right of the  `<input>` control that is rendered by the ASP.NET TextBox. Below is an example of my code. The resultant `<input>` element does not align flush to the container `<div>`, even thought the text element above it ("Some Text") is aligned flush.

```
<div style="float:left;">
  <b>Some Text</b>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtTextBox" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Style="width:300px;height:300px;"  />
</div>
```

Quite by accident I found that if I first added a `<p />` element as the first element in the `<div>` that the `<input>` element would align flush. Here is an example ...

```
<div style="float:left;">
  <p />
  <b>Some Text</b>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtTextBox" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Style="width:300px;height:300px;"  />
</div>
```

Does anyone know why this is? Why does the `<input>` element not align flush to the `<div>`, yet when adding a `<p />` do the `<div>` it does?

UPDATE - I found the issue was Internet Explorer compatibility mode. It was enabled and therefore not following the CSS rules. After disabling compatibility mode the textbox lined up properly. Thanks for all the answers. They were ALL great and helped me track down the problem. +1 to all. I answered the post so as to make it easier for future readers to find the answer.

Comment: This problem must be related to your CSS.  jsFiddle does not duplicate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/VVfc3/.  Additionally, the output of that tag would be a `<textarea>`, not an `<input>`, because you have the mode set to multiline.

Comment: Some companies, like mine, have compatibility mode enabled by default via group policy. Most users are not smart enough to turn it off. It can't hurt to make sure your site degrades well enough for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered what the issue was. I was using Internet Explorer v8 with compatibility mode enabled. I am not sure why it was enabled but as soon as I disabled compatability mode the textbox aligned just as it should.

Comment: Reason #6394 why you should never, EVER use IE as your test browser. Always, always use a modern browser (anything but IE) to initially test your markup. Then look to see how much IE screws everything up. But the quirks and bugs in IE are well known, as are the hacks to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem when I test your example, the TextBox is flush to the edge of the `div` at the top, right and bottom (with *Some Text* on the bottom left).

There must be other CSS affecting your layout.

I'd suggest using Firebug, IE's `F12` developer tools or Chrome's `Ctrl-Shift-J` developer tools (dependent on your browser) to have a look at the HTML that's created.  That should give you the answers you need.

Comment: Good idea. I will try that. Perhaps I can see where the padding is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what asp does with this and your p element is invalid in html as you have it. Remove that.

You probably need to set your padding or margin to zero on the input element.

Are you using a doctype?

Comment: I am using the following doctype ... `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because `<p>` is a block element. You can do what you are wanting to do by adding a div around your inner content (nesting a div inside your existing div)

```
<div style="float:left;">   
    <div>   
        <b>Some Text</b>   
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtTextBox" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Style="width:300px;height:300px;"  />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion of using an inner `<div>` and it worked. The padding was eliminated. Just curious as to why one should have to do this. The content is already in a container. Why is surrounding it with another container getting rid of the padding?

Answer (score 1):

1. check if you have correct **doctype** on top of your page
2. use **vertical-align** style in the text container div:    `<span style="vertical-align:middle; font-weight:bold;">Some Text</span>`

.

```
   <div style="float:left;">
      <span style="vertical-align:middle; font-weight:bold;">Some Text</span>
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtTextBox" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Style="width:300px;height:300px;"  />
     </div>
```

Comment: `valign` doesn't exist in CSS.  The closest is `vertical-align`, which applies to the element itself rather than its contents.

Comment: Wouldn't the `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` need to after and outside the `<div>` in question?